# Eliminate Circular Reference Tableau/Order of Calculation

Tags: excel, tableau-api, circular-dependency, circular-reference, tabpy

I am new here but hoping that I can get some better answers than on the Tableau community.

I am working to create a calculator tool within Tableau. It is a bit of a strange thing to do within Tableau but so far it is working well until I came across this problem.

I want to calculate a tax asset value available for each year and applied (or used) for each year then calculate the remaining value and carry it forward to the next year.

The calculation is: (best seen in the Tableau image)

Added tax deduction **(D)**=

IF EBITDA**(A)**<0 then EBITDA **(A)** * - 1 + Depreciation **(B)**

ELSE Depreciation **(B)**

Opening Balance **(C)** = lookup CF Tax Deduction **(G)**,-1

Available Tax deduction **(E)**=

Opening Balance (OB tax) **(C)**+ Added Tax Deduction **(D)**

Used Tax Deduction **(F)**=

IF EBITDA **(A)**>0 then min(Available Tax Deduction **(E)**, EBITDA **(A)**) //-this is because you cannot deduct more tax than your income

Carryforward (CF Tax Deduction) **(G)**=

Available Tax Deduction **(E)** - Used Tax Deduction **(F)**

The calculation works in excel but creates a circular reference in Tableau.

Anyone have suggestions as to how to avoid the circular reference? As soon as I enter in the formula for Used Tax Deduction I get a circular reference. I am now trying to solve using tabpy/python as well.

[How it looks in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn0GB.png)

[How it looks in Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umrR8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup cannot handle recursiveness that you implicitly entered through the circular reference of G(t) to G(t-1). (Where G(t) means the carryforward of the current time period, and G(t-1) is the same of the previous period.)
If I simplify a bit the above calculations, this is what I get:
G(t) = E(t) - F(t)
Then replacing E(t) gives:
G(t) = C(t) + D(t) - F(t)
Where C(t) is effectively G(t-1), therefore:
G(t) = G(t-1) + D(t) - F(t)

Tableau's recommended solution for such recursive formulae is the PREVIOUS_VALUE().
Try to implement this
G(t) = PREVIOUS_VALUE(0) + D(t) - F(t)
or simply put: G = PREVIOUS_VALUE(0) + D - F
(PREVIOUS_VALUE(0) starts with zero value in the first round of the calculations.)